# Angular.js - Had to use $apply() even though a $digest() was already in progress -why?

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular.js Service, I had to use `$rootScope.$apply()` so the scope primitive values would update in the view.

```
  function scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state){
    //always worried about name collisions, so not 
    //useing $ to be safe
    modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';
    modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
    $rootScope.$apply();
    setTimeout(function() {
      return modalInstance.close();
    }, TIME_CLOSE_MODAL);
    state.forceReload();
  }
```

For learning...I am curious:

1) `$digest()` is cheaper than `$apply()` since it is just to local scope...but would this matter on `$rootScope` since it would transverse down to all child scopes?

2) For experimenting, I tried `rootScope.$digest()` and I got a error message saying a digest was already in progress. If this is so-

- a) why didn't this error occur when `$apply()` was used since it also calls `$digest()`.
- b) Since, a `$digest()` is already in progress, why did I have to use `$apply()` to make the view update with the new scope member values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$digest()` is a trigger for watchers only, when `$apply` - 1st runs logic wrapped by `$apply` method and only after runs `$rootScope.$digest()`

> why didn't this error occur when $apply() was used since it also calls $digest()

`$exceptionHandler` doesn't handle `$scope.$digest` when `$scope.$apply` does (try/catch)

---

*Tips:*

- Its not good practice to use `setTimeout` when Angular provides `$timeout` method.
- Instead to call `$rootScope.$apply();`

I would better use block style like:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function(){                    
 // do your stuff here
});
```

You always can check if code runs the digest cycle with some method:

```
isScopeOutCycle: function () {
        return $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$root.$$phase != '$digest';
}
```

Comment: This is strange...I tried block style...when using `$rootScope.$apply(function(){ modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success'; modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';});` it wouldn't. Why is this?